# Re-send post request to antoher server

Tags: node.js, request, http-post, http-proxy

I would like to re-send any POST request from my server (1234 port) to another server (another.server.com:80). Note: Post requests are soap calls.

This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

var LISTEN_PORT = 1234;
var HOST = 'another.server.com';
var PORT = 80;

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(LISTEN_PORT);

function onRequest(client_req, client_res) {    
    var options = {
        hostname: HOST,
        port: PORT,
        path: client_req.url,
        method: 'POST'
    };

    var proxy = http.request(options, function (res) {
        res.pipe(client_res, {
            end: true
        });
    });

    client_req.pipe(proxy, {
        end: true
    });
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I think I need use client_req headers and client_req body but I don't know how do it